# Help in installing the XDS pacakge

Tags: 20.04, software-installation

I am trying to install `XDS` package file  `XDS-INTEL64_Linux_x86_64.tar.gz` from following website

https://xds.mr.mpg.de/html_doc/downloading.html

and following the instructions given there for installation.

However, it doesn't seems to work. It gives the following message.

```
 $xds_par 

***** XDS ***** (VERSION Jun 30, 2023  BUILT=20230630)   4-Jan-2024
Author: Wolfgang Kabsch
Copy licensed until 31-Aug-2024 to
academic users for non-commercial applications
No redistribution.

!!! ERROR !!! CANNOT OPEN OR READ XDS.INP
```

I will be grateful, if somebody here can help me out ?

Comment: This sounds like a usage issue, rather than an installation issue - did you also download and extract the [XDS_html_doc.tar.gz](https://xds.mr.mpg.de/XDS_html_doc.tar.gz) archive? It appears to contain some template .INP files that you can modify, plus documentation describing the parameters.

Comment: @steeldriver, I did, I am trying to run XDS template, then it is giving the same error, Is an XDS viewer required?

Comment: I am not familiar with the software - if you copy one of the provided templates, it does seem to be necessary to rename it exactly as `XDS.INP` but beyond that I do not know. Regardless, your issue doesn't seem to be Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

The tarball contain some executables, you need only to extract the files. To execute the command `./xds`. From the error message, you need to create a `XDS.INP` file. Here are some examples [here](https://wiki.uni-konstanz.de/xds/index.php/XDS.INP#Example_XDS.INP_files_for_ADSC,_MarCCD_and_Pilatus_detectors). Here is how to solve some [errors codes](https://wiki.uni-konstanz.de/xds/index.php/Problems).

To cleanly install the program, you need to add the extracted directory to your `PATH`:

> Alternatively, you could edit your standard personal initialization file ( `~/.bashrc or ~/.bash_login` or `~/.zshrc` , e.g. ) to include the line

> ```
> export PATH="/full_path_name_of_downloaded_XDS_directory:$PATH"
> ```

Comment: NOT working even if doing the suggested thing. Please help

Comment: @explorer Put the XDS.INP in the extracted directory.